# Unexpected changes when running xcode project

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, user-experience

When I try to build and run the project at first it looks ok (everything runs the way it should) but after a few seconds the screen disappears and a Hello World app (which I created a while ago) appears. This also happens with the other apps I've built, how can I stop the Hello World app from running? Once it appears I can’t change it back to the project I want to run, regardless of how many times I click the screen. I have even deleted the file and somehow it’s still occurring?

My ContentView.swift is:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The App delegate:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
    }
}
```

Scene Delegate:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: This is a unusual situation, people may help you better if you share some codes, especially viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear functions. Are you using launch Screen ?

Comment: might be you are using same bundle Identifier, remove hello word app from device or change bundle Identifier of that application.

Comment: @PramodShukla I've just checked that and it doesn't let me change the bundle identifier, it shows up as fixed text in a slightly darker color than the Bundle identifier label and I'm not given the option of changing it, there's no input box, is there something I can do about this?

Comment: Change it from xcode and then run